# Sum imported range row-wise

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with data in three columns, lets say from E26 to G47. What I want is to display the row-wise sum of this data in another spreadsheet, so the cell E26 of the other spreadsheet contains the sum of E26 to G26 from the first sheet. I tried to implement it in code, but I was unsuccessful:

```
=SUM(ImportRange("key"; "sheet!E26:G47"))
```

This sums the whole data of rows and columns in one cell.

```
=SUM(ImportRange("key"; "sheet!E26:G26"))
```

This does nothing.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(ImportRange("key";"sheet!E26:G47");{1;1;1}))`